# Как непрерывно для пользователей перенести базу данных mysql

Tags: php, mysql, база-данных, laravel

Имеется сайт с постоянным онлайном около 2к пользователей.
Есть задача перенести базу данных с одного сервера на другой, без потерь данных.

данные в бд меняться очень часто, из-за чего невозможно просто сделать дамп и поставить его на другой сервер.

структура базы данных и версия mysql не меняються, только место хранения данных.

Сайт на Laravel PHP (не много изменено ядро)
Mysql 5.7

Как совершить непрерывный перенос?

Comment: на любых серверах есть отключения по причине технического обслуживания. Если вы в 4 ночи, скажем, в понедельник устроите такое отключение, ничего страшного не случится

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Поднимаете такой же сервер, настраиваете репликацию (как slave, рабочий сервер будет master). Как будете готовы, перепрописываете везде ссылки на новый сервер и делаете его мастером (ну или отключаете репликацию вообще).

Comment: Вы хоть раз запускали репликацию? Потому что судя по вашему ответу - нет. Для запуска репликации необходимо **остановить сервер**, включить репликацию, **снять начальный(нулевой) дамп**, запустить сервер, запустить слейва, **влить в него начальный(нулевой) дамп**, запустить синхронизацию с мастера, и только теперь можно менять роли сервера(слейв<->мастер). Я не вижу тут непрерывности.

Comment: Я спорить не буду, почитать можете, например, тут https://4te.me/post/perenos-mysql/

Comment: https://yadi.sk/i/WU2DXYu0frKP0w Это по вашей ссылке, итого без остановки опять не выйдет.

Comment: Рестарт сервера - это не те страшные затратные по времени манипуляции, что вы написали выше =) Но так-то согласен, вообще, даже без минимального перерыва, наверное, не обойтись. Хотя, если уж так критично, то можно поизвращаться, навешать триггеров, написать обработки и "вручную" самостоятельно переносить данные. Только стоит ли овчинка выделки...

Comment: Скажите, а что из того что написано в моем комментарии первом **не нужно** проделывать для запуска репликации? что там такого страшного чего не описано по вашей же ссылке? И собственно мой ответ и был о том что в MySQL это сделать непрерывно - нельзя. А в перезапуске страшно то что если база весит прилично - после перезапуска горячие данные **не** будут находится в кэше, и часть запросов может работать крайне медленно